# VBA - Define string to worksheet.name without reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and got that problem which I don't know how to fix.
I have a workbook with some sheets and I create a new workbook for each sheet in that first one with the name of the sheets. That works...
Now, I declare a variable of type string which defines the path to one of these new workbooks.
After defining that string I use that in the open function and when i change something in that workbook i opened, it also changes it in the worksheet where i get the name from(e.g. the name of the worksheet, like below)

```
Public Sub ProcessWorksheet(ByVal Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet)
     Dim fileName As String
     Dim currProFile as Workbook
     Dim currProSheet as Worksheet
     fileName ="some path" & "\" & worksheet.name & ".xlsx"
     Set currProFile = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
     Set currProSheet = currProFile.ActiveSheet
     currProSheet.name = "DATA"
End Sub
```

So I think there is a reference to that worksheet i just use for the name cause of that worksheet.name.
My question is: How can I get the name without a reference to the worksheet.

I hope it is all cleal and thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I started all over again and just used the most important code and now it works. I don't know why but it does. So I think it was just an error by Excel itself. 
Anyways thank you braX for editing advice